# Define the relative path when clover.xml is generated in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, wordpress, sonarqube, phpunit

I'm running integration tests on my WordPress plugin with PHPUnit, and when I generate a coverage, and `clover.xml` file, the file name attribute in the `clover.xml` will have absolute path to my file, e.g.

```xml
<file name="/Users/denis/vagrant-local/www/project/public_html/wp-content/plguins/my-plugin/file-that-is-tested.php">
```

Since I need to send this file to SonarQube, I need to modify this file every time I send it to SonarQube so that I only have relative path (starting from `wp-config` folder)

```xml
<file name="wp-content/plguins/my-plugin/file-that-is-tested.php">
```

If I send the first version, SonarQube will report the code coverage as 0.0%, if I send the other one, it will show some coverage (it differs from the one PHPUnit creates, but that's not important).

Is there a way to specify this file name attribute in the PHPUnit config or do I need to run a bash script every time I run tests to delete this extra part?

### EDIT

The `phpunit.xml.dist` looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
  backupGlobals="false"
  backupStaticAttributes="false"
  beStrictAboutCoversAnnotation="true"
  bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
  colors="true"
  convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
  convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
  convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
  printerClass="Codedungeon\PHPUnitPrettyResultPrinter\Printer"
  stopOnError="false"
  stopOnFailure="false"
  stopOnIncomplete="false"
  stopOnSkipped="false"
  verbose="true"
  >
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="integration">
      <directory prefix="test-" suffix=".php">./tests/integration/</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
  <filter>
    <whitelist>
      <directory>./</directory>
      <exclude>
        <directory>./node_modules</directory>
        <directory>./vendor</directory>
        <directory>./tests</directory>
        <directory suffix=".php">./src/old</directory>
      </exclude>
    </whitelist>
  </filter>
  <logging>
    <log type="coverage-html" target="tests/_reports/coverage" lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="80" />
    <log type="coverage-clover" target="tests/_reports/clover.xml"/>
    <log type="coverage-php" target="tests/_reports/logs/coverage.cov"/>
    <log type="junit" target="tests/_reports/logs/logfile.xml"/>
  </logging>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: Where does the SonarQube agent run? And can you share the related parts from your phpunit.xml configuration file?

Comment: The SonarQube scan happens on my Jenkins machine, but I'm running the tests locally. I'll put the `phpunit.xml.dist` in the question.

Comment: Did you found any solution for this problem? I run tests in a docker container so I also have to manipulate those paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a Symfony command that will basically just search-replace part of the absolute path and remove it

https://github.com/dingo-d/woo-solo-api/tree/develop/bin

Then you can use it in your composer scripts like

```json
    "scripts": {
        "test:coverage": [
            "@php ./vendor/bin/codecept run Integration --coverage --coverage-xml --coverage-html --ansi",
            "@php bin/console clean-coverage /Users/denis.zoljom/Sites/personal/plugins-testing/ --ansi"
        ]
    },
```

Or whatever suite you are using. The second command will remove the absolute part of the path in the `coverage.serialized` and `coverage.xml` files.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the seed linux command to replace too:

```
"test-unit-cover": [
    "phpdbg -qrr vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration tests/config/phpunit-unit-cover.xml --coverage-clover tests/coverage/coverage-unit/coverage.xml --log-junit tests/config/junit.xml -d memory_limit=1024M",
    "sed -i 's+/var/www/html/++g' tests/coverage/coverage-unit/coverage.xml"
]
```